# Java Format String Spacing

Tags: java, formatting, format, string-formatting

I've been looking through the forum to find an exact answer to this, but have been unable to do so. Here is my code:

```
String item = String.format("%-6s $%-6.2f Number in Inventory: %-3d", this.getBarcode(), this.getPrice(), this.getInventory());
```

The output looks like this for two items put in:

```
DR4423 $700.04 Number in Inventory: 24 
LD342  $1234.24 Number in Inventory: 425
```

The output should look like this, with an extra character space in the price for Number in Inventory to line up:

```
DR4423 $ 700.04 Number in Inventory: 24 
LD342  $1234.24 Number in Inventory: 425
```

How do I make the "Number in Inventory" line up? It looks like the first item in the example lost an empty character space as it only has 5 digits instead of 6 for the price. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I need there to be exactly 6 character spaces for the price. Edits to the question to show expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use:

```
String.format("%-6s $%-7.2f Number in Inventory: %-3d", this.getBarcode(), this.getPrice(), this.getInventory());
```

Or, if you want the space added to the front:

```
String.format("%-6s $%#7.2f Number in Inventory: %-3d", this.getBarcode(), this.getPrice(), this.getInventory());
```

Notice the `%-7` instead of `%-6`. The period is counted as a character.

Comment: That worked similar to the \t, without extra spaces from the tab. Great answer, but I am looking for a space after the $ sign.

Comment: @javanewb2.0 Try using a hash `#` instead of dash `-`. :)

Comment: The hash # did exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`-` in `%-6.2f` means you want passed number to be aligned to left, like:

```
|123,45|
|123,40|
|123,00|
|12,00 |
|1,00  |
```

If you want to align your number to right like:

```
|123,45|
|123,40|
|123,00|
| 12,00|
|  1,00|
```

then simply remove this `-`.

You should should also probably set minimal used length to `7` since `.` also takes some space which means that to produce

```
| 700.04|
 1234567
```

you need 7 characters.

So try with `%-6s $%7.2f Number in Inventory: %-3d`

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a `\t` between the price and 'Number' should work just fine in your case.

Comment: That worked for how my expected output did read, but I missed a space. I updated it to put a space between the $ and the price when the price does not have 6 digits. This is how I am looking to format it.